# How to limit the height of modal in a responsive design without using overflow hidden?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Apparently Bootstrap modal view height are not responsive.  [sample can be find here] (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
I would like my modal height to get smaller based on users device size choice. How can I achieve it without using

```
overflow: hidden;
```

which seems cuts off the modal content. I don't neither want to use `overflow-y: scroll;`

```html
@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .my-dialog .modal-dialog {
        width: 900px;
        max-height: 750px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen to the content if you don't want it hidden or scrollable? How do you want users to be able to see content beyond the height of the modal?

Comment: I have `overflow-y: scroll;` defined by other div. So, when ever the content is too big, horizontal scroll bar is shows up. So, I don't want to add additional scroll bar in my @media.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have ever heard of the CSS length units `vh`, `vw`, `vmin`, `vmax`. They could be the solution to your problem.

From [<length> - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) from  the Mozilla Developer Network:

- `1vw` = 1% of the width of the viewport.
- `1vh` = 1% of the height of the viewport.
- `1vmin` = 1% of the minimum value between the height and the width of the viewport.
- `1vmax` = 1% of the maximum value between the height and the width of the viewport.

In your case what you are looking for is the unit `vh`.

You may want to check the [browser support table for the viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) though.